# How do you find the child contract address when deployed from a factory?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, factory

I'm experimenting with the OpenZeppelin crowdsale contracts, using the [MintedCrowdsale example](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales#minted-crowdsale).

When this is deployed, hardhat logs out the contract address for `MyCrowdsaleDeployer`.

**Question: Where can I find the contract addresses for `MyToken` and `MyCrowdsale`?**

I am able to retrieve the token contract info in the hardhat console with `ethers.getContractAt("MyToken", MyCrowdsaleDeployer_Address);`, so it seems they are deployed *somewhere*

For example, I'd like to have:

1. The `MyToken` contract address, to import into MetaMask to see the balance
2. The `MyCrowdsale` contract address, to send test ETH into and mint new `MyToken`

Calling the child contract methods on `MyCrowdsaleDeployer` doesnt work at all. Maybe this is expected (maybe those methods need to be explicitly proxied?)

Comment: The recommended approach to obtain a data generated during a transaction execution is to generate an event with the data as parameter. If the contract is already deployed I suggest to add the whole code to the question so we can suggest alternatives.